# Paypal developer account uk

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I want to use paypal sandbox accounts for some testing, and I watched a great youtube vid on how. But when I try to create a developer account it says at the top that only US businesses can use REST APIs. I don't know what this means, but the form is set up for US costomers with ZIP and 3-digit code for telephone number.

Long and short, can I use this service in the UK? If so how? Do I just enter my details in the American form?

Any help appreciated,

Robin.